# How to subclass an Abstract Base Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have an ABC:

```
class Template_ABC(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, data=None, model=None):

        self._data = data
        self._model = model

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_more_stuff(self):
        pass
```

I normally have a class of ABC, for example:

```
class Example_of_ABC(Template_ABC):

    def do_stuff(self):
        # Do stuff here

    def do_more_stuff(self):
        pass
```

Now, I want to subclass Example-of_ABC class. The only way I can do is as as follows:

```
class Subclass_of_Example_of_ABC(Example_of_ABC):

    def __init__(self, data=None, model=None):
        super().__init__(data, model)

    def do_more_stuff(self):
        # Do more stuff here
```

The issue with this way, is that I have to update my def _init__() for every subclass of the ABC. Is there anyway for the subclass to inherit all the inits from the ABC?

Comment: What do you mean " inherit all the inits from the ABC"?  The subclass will use the first `__init__` it finds in the [method resolution order.](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

Comment: *I have to update my def _init__() for every subclass of the ABC* - who said you that?

Comment: You only need to override methods that are specifically decorated with abstractmethod.